# Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings(): Argument #1 ($bindings) must be of type array

Tags: php, laravel

**singers_id is array
["2","4"]
**

**my cotroller**

```
  $albums =  Album::join('tracks', 'albums.artist_id', '=', 'tracks.artist_id')
        ->where('albums.verified',1)->get();
```

**my blade**

```
   @php
                    
                    
                    $names = DB::table('singers')->whereIn('id', $album->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name')->toArray();
    
@endphp
{{implode(' & ', $names)}}
</a></span>
```

error -laravel Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings(): Argument #1 ($bindings) must be of type array, string given in laravel

how to solve this error

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
 $names = DB::table('singers')->whereIn('id', $album->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name')->toArray();
```

to

```
 $names = DB::table('singers')->whereIn('id', [$album->singers_id])->pluck('singers_name')->toArray();
```

`whereIn` value must be `array`, look like you put `int` instead

Comment: Array ( ) the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

When using `->whereIn()`, your second parameter must be an array. You're currently passing string. Also it's not a good practice to execute database queries inside blade file.